# Reading a file with MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I work currently with the MFC template of Visual Studio 2019 and C++. The program can write text files. But it can not read (text) files from other programs. It shows 效汬⁯潗汲 when I use CEditView (In the .txt file is "Hello World"). When I use CRichEditView it shows nothing. What can I do?

Comment: In your main.cpp in line 198 you could change the value of the variable.

Comment: MFC uses 16 bits per character. If the file uses 8bit character formats like utf8, you will need to convert it before displaying.

Comment: `"Hello World"` in ANSI converts to `"效汬⁯潗汲..."` in UTF16. So your program is compiled as Unicode. Read the text from file, then convert the text to UTF16 `CString unicode_text = CA2W(text_from_file)`, or `CA2W(text_from_file, CP_UTF8)` send `unicode_text` to your windows.

Comment: I use this for reading and writing files with MFC as it does all of the encoding handling for me: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7958/CTextFileDocument